# Is SHFileOperation() call asynchronous?

Tags: file, msdn, recycle-bin

ALL,

SHFileOperation() call - is it synchronous or asynchronous? I want to send some files to the Recycle Bin...

I can't find this info in MSDN.

Thank you.

Comment: @HarveyPham, how do you know? Do you have a link to the doc or you just tried it?

Comment: I used it before so I know it is synchronous. Also, if you look at MSDN docs, if the call is asynchronous, the document should say so.